# How to implement Java 8 Stream API using Java 7 or older?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I was asked this question in a job interview (Microsoft).
methods to implement for example:
 **.stream(), .filter(), .map() , flatMap() , min() , count() , reduce() , groupBy()**
etc

It's quite an open question but I think is an interesting one.

Thanks

Comment: implement yourself? well, `filter`, `map`, `min`...  may be `groupBy` could be implemented fairly trivially, I mean `guava` did it, before java-8. By trivial I mean trivial enough for the job interview answer.

Comment: I'm guessing it could be implemented the same way, just without lambdas, which would be a huge mess and not really readable, but it could have been done

Comment: @Lino why would that be a huge mess? I do work on a jdk-7 project using guava quite OK for when stream operations are not an option

Comment: @Eugene I thought about the way to use anonymous classes instead of lambdas. Which *would* be a huge mess. But of course it must not be done *exactly* the same way as in java8.

Comment: @Lino right, your words would be verbosity in such a case I assume - which makes perfect sense

Comment: @Eugene yeah exactly, verbosity is what i tried to explain :)

Comment: We did this for a project and it works reasonably, even if it can’t compete with the Java 8 syntax. However, you can have pre-built existing functions or factories based on Generics, Reflection and code generation, e.g. `method("isEmpty").asPredicate(String.class)`; not as concise as `String::isEmpty`, but still shorter than implementing the `Predicate` using an anonymous inner class. But that’s not the question; the question was “How to implement the Stream API” and the answer would be, just like any other interface, wouldn’t it?

Answer (score 3):

One way to get an ability to use StreamAPI in your Java7 and Java6 projects add a streamsupport library https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport Streamsupport is a backport of the Java 8 java.util.function (functional interfaces) and java.util.stream (streams) API for users of Java 6 or 7

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example: [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API). It implements almost all stream APIs for Android/Java 7 by iterators.

Answer (score -1):

I would not waste time creating those functions myself as it also implies quite rigorous testing. I would rather use [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/). It works with any Java starting from 6 and has all of these features (including lambdas) plus many others. Additionally it provides quite good compatibility with the core Java partially solving deficiencies of generics implementation.